# 'Explode' array then only display first element

Tags: php

$value is a string of URLs. Each URL hotlinks to a JPG file and this code displays those on a page. Each URL is separated by a comma.

If I only want to display the first 1 or 2 images, what do I do? I tried to add a limiter to the explode function but I think I'm missing something because it  doesn't quite work

```
$images = explode(',', $value);

$value = '';
foreach ($images as $im){
    $value .= '<img src="'. $im . '" />';
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($value)`  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) is your friend!

```
$images = array_slice(explode(',', $value), 0, 2);
//extracts 2 elements, starting with index 0
$value = '';
foreach ($images as $im){
    $value .= '<img src="'. $im . '" />';
}
```

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you! Please consider accepting my answer if it solves your question ;-)